# comment.getFrom().getId is Null restfb facebook comments

Tags: comments, restfb, facebook4j

I am getting NullPointerException while calling  getFrom() on commnent
comment.getFrom().getId() .... Throws NullPointerException .....

I am using Application Token .....

**Obtaining Token**

```
AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient(Version.VERSION_2_8).obtainAppAccessToken(
                        entry.getValue().getCredential().getAppId(),
                        entry.getValue().getCredential().getAppSecret());
                String token = accessToken.getAccessToken();
```

**Creating Connection and getting Page Feed and Posts**

```
            Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject(getPageURL(), Page.class,
                    Parameter.with("since", sDate),
                    Parameter.with("until", uDate));

            Connection<Post> pageFeed = facebookClient.fetchConnection(page.getId() + "/feed", Post.class,
                    Parameter.with("limit", 100), Parameter.with("summary", 1),
                    Parameter.with("since",sDate),
                    Parameter.with("until",uDate));
```

**Getting Post Details from the Page**

```
      Post postDetails = facebookClient.fetchObject(post.getId(), 
      Post.class, 
      Parameter.with("fields",
           "from,actions,message,story,to,likes.limit(0).summary(true),
           comments.limit(0).summary(true),shares.limit(0).summary(true)"));
```

**Getting comments of Post and Calling Comment.getFrom()**

```
      Connection<Comment> comments = 
      facebookClient.fetchConnection(post.getId() + "/comments", 
      Comment.class,
                Parameter.with("limit", 100));
        boolean hasNext = true;
        while (hasNext && comments.getData().size() > 0) {
            for (Comment comment : comments.getData()) {
                currentCount++;
                currentCommentId=comment.getId();
                if (isValidUser(comment.getFrom().getId())  && (!isCommentsSearchEnabled() || filterCommentFeed(comment.getMessage()))) {
                    writeToSummaryFile(post.getId(), comment, currentCount);
                    getCommentsOfComment(comment.getId());
                }

            }

            if (comments.hasNext()) {
                comments = facebookClient.fetchConnectionPage(comments.getNextPageUrl(), Comment.class);
            } else
                hasNext = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the fields you like to fetch, so please change

```
facebookClient.fetchConnection(post.getId() + "/comments", 
  Comment.class,
            Parameter.with("limit", 100));
```

to

```
facebookClient.fetchConnection(post.getId() + "/comments", 
  Comment.class,
            Parameter.with("limit", 100), Parameter.with("fields","id,from");
```

Comment: Still does not work even added the Parameter.with  
                 Connection<Comment> comments = facebookClient.fetchConnection(post.getId()+"/comments", Comment.class, Parameter.with("fields", "id, from, created_time, message"));

Comment: check the returned json. You can use a debugger or logging  on debug.

Comment: `JsonObject cobj= facebookClient.fetchObject("1434462429970368_1434463249970286", JsonObject.class, Parameter.with("fields", "id,from,message,metatags"), Parameter.with("limit", "100"));`   What it returns is only ID and Message                                                                  `{"id":"1434462429970368_1434463249970286","message":"but PTCL 4jee would die"}`

Comment: this happens on all comments or only on that one?

Comment: All Comments and Posts - Sometimes if the Comment i / Post is by the page admin then i get the FROM Object, otherwise its NULL